# Getting SWT error when using formula step in pentaho kettle on linux

Tags: swt, pentaho, kettle

I'm using Pentaho Kettle 8.2 on fedora 28 64 bits;

I get this error

"Unable to open dialog for this step
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="](java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:Could not load SWT library. Reasons: no swt-mozilla-gtk-4335 in java.library.path..."

"...libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory..."

I've been looking for an answer but all of I have found do not solve this problem.

The last on was instal xulrunner and set MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to xulrunner directory.

thanks !!

[EDITED]
Print screen from error
[image]

Comment: Please provide the full, *complete* stack trace or error message

Comment: I'm not sure if I could because it is a message box. I can't copy and paste here. Maybe put print screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no swt-mozilla-gtk-4332 in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901117/no-swt-mozilla-gtk-4332-in-java-library-path)

Comment: Thanks to find it @Shashwat. This error at first doesn't make any sense for me.
Install an old webkit version is strange. A message In bash script sounds not be a necessity "...Use a Mozilla with Gtk2 and Fte enabled.
but further up  same script there is this message   if [ -z "$HASWEBKITGTK" ] && [ "1" != "$SKIP_WEBKITGTK_CHECK" ]; then
               echo "WARNING:  no libwebkitgtk-1.0 detected, some features will be unavailable"
              echo " Consider installing the package with apt-get or yum."
              echo "e.g. 'sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0'"
What d u say ?

Comment: yum install libwebkitgtk

Answer (score 3):

For those having a very similar error:

> SWT on GTK 2.x detected. It is reccomended to use SWT on GTK 3.x and
> Webkit2 API.

Edit ./spoon.sh and look for the line

> SWT_GTK3=0

Change that value to 1. It worked in Debian 10. I have installed libwebgtk-4.0.0.

Got the info translating this article in Google Translate: https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1686155