# How to install the libwebkitgtk package on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, gtk, coronasdk, solar2d

So I am trying to install Solar2D (formerly known as Corona SDK) to make a mobile game. After installing the dependencies, when I run Solar 2D I get the following error:

```
/home/user/CoronaSimulator/CoronaSimulator: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried installing libwebkitgtk using `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` but I get the following message in Terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-1.0-0' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Maybe use newer version of Solar2d:)

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but with a different program that requires this dependency. I was hoping I could install the Bionic version of libwebkitgtk but no luck, only resulted in a broken package.

Comment: Please, refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/413530/libwebkitgtk-1-0-0-package

Answer (score 41):

Following the steps [here](https://github.com/subgraph/Vega/issues/177) fixed the issue for me

Open terminal and write this:

1. sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Add this entry to the file and save:

`deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe`

3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 -> if you are using Vega and jdk of 64 bits

   sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:i386 -> if you are using Vega and jdk of 32 bits

Comment: is this safe to do !!

Comment: This also does not work on Kubuntu 20.04.3 and Eclipse 06-2021.

Comment: Can I remove repository after installing the library?

Comment: was getting `E: The repository 'http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.`

Comment: so, ended up using this instead - `deb [trusted=yes] http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe`

Comment: @keemahs same error, but solution didn't work for me

Comment: @keemahs `deb [trusted=yes] http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe` worked for on Ubuntu in WSL on windows 11

Answer (score 4):

KNIME has a similar dependency.
In Debian, the new needed libraries are:

libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37

libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2

(Using the standard repositories)

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37

sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully installed libwebkitgtk package using the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -qq software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [trusted=yes] http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -qq libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but I solved my similar problem by discovering that a prior older dependency was needed to be installed first before **libwebkitgtk-3** would successfully install. Specifically, I needed **libjavascriptcoregtk** to be installed on the system *before* I could successfully attempt to install libwebkitgtk. I'm not sure if libjavascriptcoregtk was needed by libwebkitgtk or by the program I'm using, but either way, it was apparently required first.

So there may be some other dependencies you need to have satisfied first before your install can proceed.

Comment: this works. Solved my problem to use pulse secure in ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

This solution is work for me:

First you need to install aptitude:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Then you can install the package:

```
sudo aptitude install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Comment: This did not work for me on a default Ubuntu 20.04 install. Error was "No candidate version found for libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 Unable to apply some actions, aborting"

Comment: Didn't work for me either