# org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/firefox'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons

Tags: java, ant, swt, build.xml, xulrunner

**َUPDATE:**
My target: I'm going to build [Zekr software](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zekr/) with new library in Debian Repository.Already Zekr was in old debian repo.
Now, I have an old code written by `java` and I compile and run it under JDK11 and new version of dependencies library via `ant clean;ant compile;ant run`
Then I get the following errors:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/firefox'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-mozilla-gtk-4233 in java.library.path: [lib]
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path: [lib]
    /home/mohsen/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk-4233.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/mohsen/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
)
```

At first you have to change line 92, attribute source and target to 1.6 , and at same line add `includeantruntime="false"` Then in javac directive, add `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:-options"/>`

The given code uses SWT library.
How can I solve it?
How can I tell to `build.xml` to use new version of my libs?

By the way, Debian removed `xulrunner` from their packages.

Comment: #1 Maven is an option for you? #2 Could you share us the ant project with a minimal and reproducible version of your project? #3 Are you trying on a linux desktop or linux shell?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/zekr/ It's not my project, I want to compitble with new version of Debian or other distro.

Comment: It was on debian at old old debian.

Comment: for example xulrunner isn't on new version of debian.

Comment: If you want to compile without any problem, at line 92, change source and target to  `1.6` value. and add `includeantruntime="false"` at same line.Then at same `javac` directive, add `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:-options"/>`

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/x11/zekr

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350384/3957754

Comment: Oh, I installed new version of `webkit`(version 4). But I have still error.

Comment: I compiled it as expected `ant compile` with empty debian, java 7 / java 11 and ant 1.9.16. I think your debian is buggy. Also zekr needs a 32-bit os